# How can I join two bones in a specific coordinate through python?

Tags: python, rigging, bones

I have been given a text file containing 28 bones where each line in the text file has the format (j,k,x,y,z) where j & k are bones and x, y, and z are the locations where these bones are supposed to be joined. I cannot seem to find a command in python for blender that allows me to connect to bones using a coordinate.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you learned that the x,y,z refers to a location at which the bones should be joined?  The concept itself doesn't make much sense, but given better context, people may be able to figure out what that means.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous because it doesn't specify whether `j` or  `k` is to be the parent at this new location, but let's assume that it's supposed to be `j`.

I'll assume you know how to read the values in, and further that `j` and `k` are text strings that contain bone names.  Your need to first find the correct armature and put it in edit mode, using code like this, perhaps:

```py
# Replace the next line with code that selects the proper armature
armature = bpy.data.armatures["Armature"]
bones = armature.edit_bones

if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_ARMATURE':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

Once you've done that, then you can accomplish your goal with code like this:

```py
parent = bones[j]
child = bones[k]
# This line moves the parent's tail to the correct location
parent.tail = (x, y, z)
# This line moves the child's head to the correct location
child.head = (x, y, z)
# The next two lines make the connect
child.parent = parent
child.use_connect = True
```

There are several simplifying assumptions here.  The most important is that `connect` means setting up a connection the way you would do it if you connected two bones manually in the editor.

Next, there is an assumption that the bones already exist and have the correct names.  If you need to create the bones, then you need code something like this for each bone:

```py
bones.new(name)
```

before you try to use the bone the first time.  This might mean keeping track of `j` and `k` values to see if you've already encountered the name.

Which brings us to the last assumption: The armature and data are "well behaved" in the sense that all of the names in the file belong to actual bones in the armature and that applying the file would not lead to attempting to make an impossible connection.  Impossible connections include creating a loop, for example.

Putting it altogether in an example that doesn't read the data in:

```py
import bpy


# Not shown: code that reads these arrays from a text file
j = ['A', 'B']
k = ['B', 'C']
x = [0, 0]
y = [0, 0]
z = [2, 4]

def connect(bones, parent_name, child_name, x, y, z):
    print(parent_name, child_name, x, y, z)
    parent = bones[parent_name]
    child = bones[child_name]
    parent.tail = (x, y, z)
    child.parent = parent
    child.head = (x, y, z)
    child.use_connect = True
    
    
# Replace the next line with code that selects the proper armature
armature = bpy.data.armatures["Armature"]


if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_ARMATURE':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    
bones = armature.edit_bones

for i in range(0,len(j)):
    print(i, j[i], k[i], x[i], y[i], z[i])
    connect(bones, j[i], k[i], x[i], y[i], z[i])
```

Comment: for those playing along at home: Yes there are better data structures; the code to read the CSV file would be only a few lines; and you don't have to move the child head because `use_connect` will do that for you.  I was trying to keep the answer as close to the format of the question as possible.